# Storyboards for OSX App in Xcode 6

Tags: macos, cocoa, storyboard, xcode6

With Xcode 6 StoryBoards were added for OSX Apps as well.
But when I create a new app in Cocoa , Storyboards button is disabled.

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 6):

Storyboards are a feature of OS X 10.10 (Yosemite). If you run Xcode 6 on 10.9 (Mavericks), you won't be able to use them.

Comment: I don't believe you can even run `xcode 6` on OSX 10.9 (Mavericks) It has a minimum requirement of 10.10 (Yosemite). Well that's what came up when I downloaded it and tried to install it I got told I need to upgrade to OSX 10.10

Comment: I have just double checked this on one of my Macs that is running OSX 10.9 still and it is telling me I need to update to 10.10 to use xcode 6.

Comment: Just having a look at the release documentation for `xcode 6` and it does actually say `"Xcode 6 Beta requires a Mac running OS X version 10.9.3 (or later) or 10.10."` so you are correct it should work. I will raise a bug with the Apple reporter.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think there are two versions.  If you download it on a 10.9 machine, you get the version that will run on 10.9.  If you download it on 10.10, you get the 10.10 version.

Comment: As of Xcode 6 beta 5, Mac Storyboards in Xcode and Apps that are created using Mac storyboards only run on Yosemite. I doubt this is a bug, but a feature that is only available in Yosemite.

Comment: Ok I found the answer. Yes 6.1 does run on Mavericks. In fact it is required if you want to create a project using Swift. For storyboards, the option will remain greyed out, but you can add them manually afterwards. No thanks to me - I had to ask a professional about this.

Comment: It is ridiculous… with Xcode 6.1.1 on OS X 10.9.5 I can create a .storyboard that I cannot in fact open.