# Xcode storyboard greyed out

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode-storyboard

I'm new to Xcode and OS X dev and would like to try out using storyboards. I've downloaded XCode 6 Beta but for some reason when I create a new project (for OS X), the option to select storyboards remains greyed out.

I've attached a screenshot and hopefully somebody will know. Perhaps I need to download something extra, but not sure.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: This is from Xcode beta (6.1). New project > OSX > Cocoa Application > Next - though I'm sure it works pretty much the same in 6.0 as well.

Comment: yea that's not really what I asked.

Comment: Thanks WD. Perhaps we can close this thread?

Comment: I updated my comment into a real answer. Hope that it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboards for OS X only work in Yosemite and above (10.10). If you are running Xcode 6 in something lower than Yosemite you will see storyboards greyed out like in your image. There is more info in this SO question found here:
[Storyboards for OSX App in Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203113/storyboards-for-osx-app-in-xcode-6)

Comment: Thanks WD. You're right. Eventhouh I could add a storyboard after I created the project on Mavericks.... i couldn't open the file. Said 10.10 was required. Will just have to wait for the official release and hopefully the new OS doesn't 'bend' either ;)