# Xcode 6.1 OSX apps using storyboard does not render window or menubar

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, xcode-storyboard

I recently ported a OSX swift based app that was using xib to storyboard. Compiling and deploying it for 10.10 works fine on a machine with Yosemite installed, the window loads. However targeting 10.9 and then running it on a VM with Mavericks installed, the window does nor the menubar loads for the app.

To further isolate the issue, I created a blank new xcode project with storyboard enabled, compiled for 10.9 and ran the app on a VM running 10.9, the same behavior is observed.

Is this a known issue with running apps on 10.9 using storyboards? Am I missing some additional runtime to execute storyboard apps on 10.9?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203113/storyboards-for-osx-app-in-xcode-6

Answer (score 2):

Storyboards are new to Yosemite. They don't work with Mavericks. If you need to maintain compatibility with 10.9, stick with plain old xibs for now.

Comment: What surprised me (and I would guess others) is that it fails silently with an app that's clearly broken but not in an obvious way.  A dialog saying why the app can't run would seem like a better user experience.