# Can my Mac OS X App use Storyboards in 10.10 and later, but not in 10.6 through 10.9?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, user-interface, interface-builder

I am working on a consulting gig in which my client got a prototype for his App to work on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) by using a storyboard.  However the App crashes on 10.9.x and earlier, because the APIs required to use storyboards in Cocoa desktop applications were not yet available.

At present the application is not very complex, so I could satisfy his immediate requirement by revising his application so as not to use storyboards at all, I would instead implement his UI "The Old-Fashioned Way", without using storyboards at all.

I'm not real sure what is the best course of action.  If I implement what I just said, he will eventually find his UI deprecated by Apple.  If I use a storyboard for 10.10 and later, but not on 10.9 and earlier then there could be twice as much work for my client to develop this code.

Note that, as a consultant, I could stand to gain by increasing my client's workload.  I don't want to do that as I regard it as unethical to take advantage of my clients by writing bad code.  I really want to do right by this fellow.

Comment: well, I can't answer your question, but I don't think your app should crash because of the storyboard. Apple introduced this concept in Xcode5 which yours OSX version should also support. Try to look into other related factors too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storyboards for OSX App in Xcode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203113/storyboards-for-osx-app-in-xcode-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Right.** Storyboards are only available in MacOS X from 10.10 (Yosemite) onward. Support for storyboards is feature of the Cocoa framework, so the fact that it doesn't exist on versions <= 10.9 means code using storyboards won't work.

> I'm not real sure what is the best course of action.

I think the most reasonable solution is to explain the situation to your client and let him decide. It's going to be a long time before .xib-based code goes away, if it ever happens, so sticking to .xib files for now is not necessarily a bad choice. On the other hand, your client might prefer to have the most forward looking app you can build, and he may not care all that much about supporting older OS versions. (Several sources indicate that as of early 2015, about half of all Macs are running Yosemite.) You'll serve your client best by giving him the information he needs to make a decision and then writing the app in accordance with his wishes.